# How to use IWizard interface to change Web properties in a custom Visual Studio Web Application Project Template

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, templates, projects-and-solutions, vs-extensibility

Trying to create a standard template for my team.

Things I'm trying to accomplish:

- Set StartAction to be a Specific Url and set the URL to be used.
- Set to use IIS rather than the development server

I have a wizard set up and gac'd and executing successfully.

Within the wizard I have the following method:

```
    public void ProjectFinishedGenerating(EnvDTE.Project project)
    {
        Configuration conf = project.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration;

        conf.Properties.Item("StartAction").Value = prjStartAction.prjStartActionURL;            
        conf.Properties.Item("StartURL").Value = "User.mvc/Login";            
    }
```

Using `MessageBox.Show()` I've seen this method get executed (twice, oddly enough), but when I open the Properties for the project, it's still set to use "Current Page."

I don't even know where to begin finding the IIS settings. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!